# Curly brackets in php sql password issue

Tags: php, sql, passwords

When I connect to på database, with php and username and a password, it can connect. But for some weird reason I have to type my password with two curly brackets. And if I manually login to the database it doesn't login with two curly brackets.

```
Username = "xxxxx";
Password = "thisis(a}password"; //thisis(a}}password  --- this is not the password, but this password is the only one accepted?
sqlsrv_connect(...);
```

is there some kind of syntax i don't know about, because i've never experienced this before.

Comment: Google for "string interpolation in php"

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work

Comment: do you use special characters in pass?

Comment: Does changing to single quotes help? `Password = 'thisis(a}password'` The only syntax with curly braces I can think of is the one to inject variables into string `$str = "someprefix${variable}and the rest"` but I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: I think it's the php driver.. for some reason Microsoft says that passwords containing a curly bracket must be escaped by another curly bracket... Was very hard to find, but yeah.. i think i will make another password without a single curly bracket, because thats a bit stupid..

Comment: @Augustas the password is `thisis(a}password` but that doesn't work, but `thisis(a}}password` works, but thats not the right password.